# Show the three lines at navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I recently updated my app to use navigation drawer in 2 activities (instead of only one, as it used to be). For this, made an DrawerActivity parent class, and I extend this class on the two activities I want to use it on. The problem is, instead of showing the three lines symbol, it shows the back arrow symbol. Previously, when I used only in the main activity the navigation drawer, it was shown as it should (with the three lines), like this:

[image: http://s17.postimg.org/y66pxf50v/JEk_FM.png]

Here's the code that I use for this:

```
drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset) {
        }
    }
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

Any ideas why it shows the back button, instead of the three lines ? Thank you.

Comment: set `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);`

Comment: @HimanshuAgarwal, if I set it as false, the it will not show any icon at all.

Comment: what do you mean by three lines? If it is what I think it is, is it not part of a theme?

Comment: @mirak, I highlighted in the picture what exactly I'm referring to.

Comment: @Phantom have a look at themes? this is quite a strange one. If you say it was there before, then backtrack and look back at what you have changed.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30594992/the-3-line-icon-for-a-hamburger-menu-isnt-appearing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, after long „battles” with it, I finally realized what was the problem. It seems that it has nothing to do with the code posted in the question, the activity was missing the onPostCreate() method with the syncState() function:

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    drawerListener.syncState();
}
```

Thank you all for the support and hope this will help others avoid forgetting the syncState() function.

Answer (score 1):

Just Add this,

```
@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout),
            (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar), R.string.navigation_drawer_open,
            R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {}.syncState();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code to this:

```
    // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button.
    // call these codes before calling "setDrawerListener(drawerListener)"
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // set up the drawerListener
    drawerListener = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
            R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
            R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(drawerListener);
```

Where `R.drawable.ic_drawer` is a icon in `drawable` resource folder which shows the three lines icon. Download `ic_drawer`  [here](https://developer.android.com/samples/NavigationDrawer/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_drawer.html) and import it into your project.

Comment: I think you understood my problem backwards. Yes, the code you mentioned should put the three lines icon on the `ActionBar`, but it doesn't. I don't want to change it to back button, I just want the three lines icon to be shown. But, for an unknown reason, it is shown the back button instead.

Comment: Thank you for the time spent editing the comment, but the result is the same, the back icon is shown instead of the three lines icon.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, removing the line `actionBarDrawerToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);` worked and replaced the back arrow with three lines again.

**setDrawerIndicatorEnabled is true by default**. By mistake, I had made it false.